# Show content always within device in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

i am stucked with a some strange problem in android which are-

1. i am working on html reader so for this i am displaying
             the webpage inside Webview in android ,So my problem is that i want
             webpage content will always be displayed within the device width that
             means on zooming also i do not need the horizontal scrollbar For this
             i was using the -
2. **w.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);**

But this is deprecated method for 4.0 its working perfect but 4.0.3 the content is going out of boundary please suggest me any solution.

1. i am having some option like fit page ,on clicking on this i want
   that
            any larger page or normal webpage will display withing the screen that
            means without horizontal and vertical scrollbar. For this i tried to
            set a factor based on device and webpage height but for portrait and
            landscape its not setting properly and sometimes page comes with
            scrollbar. Please guys suggest me any workable solution or anything
            useful things regarding this issue.

Thanks a lot in advaced

Comment: Use device width and height to display your content so that it become fit for every device . Asfor example use this code     Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
  device_height = display.getHeight();
  device_width =display.getWidth();

Comment: Hey Saurabh i tried that and get a scale value and tried to set that but if the values comes too low to meta tag reflect that otherwise in portrait mode it sets but  in landscape it appears different.